# Typing higher order functions using rest paramters and property injection in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can I properly type the following higher order function in TypeScript:

```js
const wrap = (fn1, fn2) => ({ ...rest }) => fn2({ fn1, ...rest });
```

...where `fn1`:

- is an async (probably not relevant) function whose type is named `Fn1Function`, and is defined elsewhere already

...where `fn2`:

- is an async function
- takes a single parameter as defined below
- returns a promise for a value whose type is named `Fn2Return`, and is defined elsewhere already (so, the return type of `fn2` is `Promise<Fn2Return>`)

...where the single parameter for `fn2`:

- is an object
- must include the `fn1` property
- must include all the other optional and required properties (i.e. `...rest`) as defined by variants of `fn2`

...where `wrap` returns the same type as `fn2` (i.e. `Promise<Fn2Return>`).

I am hoping to get two benefits, in particular:

- the caller of `wrap` will not be able to pass in an `fn2` parameter which itself does not take a parameter that requires `fn1` as a property without a TypeScript error
- the caller of the function *returned* by `wrap` will not be able to pass in an invalid set of properties (i.e. `...rest`) of the object parameter of `fn2` (again, this must include at least `fn1`, but also all of the other parameters `fn2` wants) without a TypeScript error

I am open to reformulating the `wrap` function to make things work.

The closest I could come to solving this was:

```js
type Fn1Function = /* ... defined elsewhere */;
type Fn2Value = /* ... defined elsewhere */;

type AnyFunction = (...args: any[]) => any;
type FirstParameter<F extends AnyFunction> = Parameters<F>[0];
type Fn2Return = Promise<Fn2Value>;

const wrap =
  <F extends (param: FirstParameter<F>) => Fn2Return>(
    fn1: Fn1Function,
    fn2: F
  ): ((param: Omit<FirstParameter<F>, "fn1">) => Fn2Return) =>
  ({ ...rest }) =>
    fn2({ fn1, ...rest });
```

This solution seems to partially work. It helps the callers of the function *returned* by `wrap` to avoid passing in an invalid object parameter. However, it doesn't constrain `fn2` so that it takes an object parameter with at least the `fn1` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We all know that 2 is better than 1 (obviously, the more the merrier!). That's why I added another generic parameter that we can use in the rest of the implementation:

```
const wrap = <
    FN1 extends (...args: any[]) => any,
    FN2 extends (ctx: any) => any,
>(
    fn1: FN1,
    // Does the first parameter match `{ fn1: FN1 }`?
    fn2: Parameters<FN2>[0] extends { fn1: FN1 }
        ? FN2
        : never, // It doesn't! Better throw an error
) => ({
    ...rest
}: Omit<Parameters<FN2>[0], "fn1"> extends infer O 
    ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } // This is just a QoL thing that simplifies the type
    : never
): Promise<Fn2Return> => fn2({ fn1, ...rest });
```

And, as a bonus, I added in two example usages, one which works properly, and one which errors (on purpose) since the provided `fn2` doesn't take a `fn1`
property.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WzP6eN)

Comment: This looks interesting. One issue I noticed, though, is that the wrapped function returns `any` instead of `Promise<Fn2Return>`, but I'll keep playing with what you posted. Thanks!

Comment: Adding `: Promise<Fn2Return>` to the end of the wrapped function's signature seems to have resolved all the issues I can see.

Comment: @ptrhvns When you update the code in the answer, consider also updating the playground link as well :)

Comment: Missed that. Will do next time.